# Magento 2- can not upload product image

Tags: magento2, product, product-images, image-upload

So I've set up a new product in my Magento storefront. All works fine, however when I try to upload an image to the product I'm getting this error:

> Could not read config file

I've checked the folder where the image would be uploaded to and it is actually there so it's been uploaded, but can't actually save the image.

I've tried to debug it and it seems the problem is in the `FileResolver.php` file in this method:

```
public function get($filename, $scope)
    {
        switch ($scope) {
            case 'global':
                $iterator = $this->moduleReader->getConfigurationFiles($filename)->toArray();
                $themeConfigFile = $this->currentTheme->getCustomization()->getCustomViewConfigPath();
                if ($themeConfigFile
                    && $this->rootDirectory->isExist($this->rootDirectory->getRelativePath($themeConfigFile))
                ) {
                    $iterator[$this->rootDirectory->getRelativePath($themeConfigFile)] =
                        $this->rootDirectory->readFile(
                            $this->rootDirectory->getRelativePath(
                                $themeConfigFile
                            )
                        );
                } else {
                    $designPath = $this->resolver->resolve(
                        RulePool::TYPE_FILE,
                        'etc/view.xml',
                        $this->area,
                        $this->currentTheme
                    );
                    if (file_exists($designPath)) {
                        try {
                            $designDom = new \DOMDocument;
                            $designDom->load($designPath);
                            $iterator[$designPath] = $designDom->saveXML();
                        } catch (\Exception $e) {
                            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                                new \Magento\Framework\Phrase('Could not read config file')
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
                break;
            default:
                $iterator = $this->iteratorFactory->create([]);
                break;
        }
        return $iterator;
    }
```

Comment: it is occurs in Magento 1 or Magento 2

Comment: @RamaChandran Magento 2

Comment: I think some of your xml files don't have read permissions. You can add before the throw statement this echo $e->getMessage();exit; to see on the screen what's the exact error.

Comment: What is the error through after display $e->getMessage();exit; please let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your xml files don't have read permissions. You can add before the throw statement this `echo $e->getMessage();exit;`  and what the is on the screen what is the error through.